# Highlight text with math signs

Tags: emphasis

I need to highlight some text with the command `\emph` whose content is "valeurAop += analogRead(mesure_aop)" : the compilation gives me an error, I think it is due to the mathematical symbols.

I tried `\emph{opvalue} $+= $ \emph{analogRead (aop_measure)` but I still get the same error:"Missing $ inserted$

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Never use underscore in text alone. If you want underscore, use a backlash preceding it, like this `\_`. That's because underscore is designed to be used in math mode to display subscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\mathit{opvalue} +=  \mathit{analogRead(aop\_measure)}$

$\mathit{opvalue}\mathrel{+=}\mathit{analogRead(aop\_measure)}$
\end{document}
```

The second example is suggested by @David Carlisle).

Comment: possibly `\mathrel{+=}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes,  with it the spacing looks better. I add this possibilities to the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks, it works very well @Zarko and David

Comment: Probably better `\mathrel+=`

Comment: @egreg Why `\mathrel+=` instead of `\mahthrel{+=}`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a math formula. In order to do this, you should

1. define a higher level commands for the variables;
2. define a math symbol for plus-equal, which should have the two parts next to each other;
3. use properly the underscore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % not necessary for the example, but recommended

\newcommand{\lvar}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand{\pluseq}{\mathrel+=}

\begin{document}

$\lvar{opvalue} \pluseq  \lvar{analogRead(aop\_measure)}$

\end{document}
```

If you later change your mind, you can decide that the argument to `\lvar` is typeset upright, boldface or whatever by just changing the definition.

With `\mathrel+=` we make the whole combination a relation symbol, which seems the appropriate choice. TeX will never add space between consecutive relation symbol, nor break a line in the middle.

[image]